# AJAX - периодический повтор запросов

Tags: ajax, php

Как это реализовать?

Может есть функция готовая? Или надо самому в цикле с таймаутом итераций делать?
Допустим, мне нужно посекундно обновлять на страничке некоторую информацию. (Значение 3-х переменных ведь не создаст особой нагрузки?)

И еще вопросик, если 1-й пользователь присвоил значение суперглобальной переменной ($_GLOBALS), то 2-й пользователь может получить это значение? Или суперглобльные переменные работают на каждого пользователя отдельно? Или как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: @Rasim Bayturin Пожалуйста, не забывайте принимать (галочка) ответы, если они отвечают на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [setInterval](http://javascript.ru/setInterval)
2. Если коротко, то нет, выражаясь Вашим языком, все переменные у каждого пользователя свои.

Comment: 1. Спасибо, это то, что мне нужно!
 2. Вы немного не так меня поняли)) Но решение нашлось.